# how to order and limit a calculation in a Google sheets =QUERY

Tags: google-sheets

My data in the range 'known' includes a column with the beginning year (E) and another with final year (F). I want to build a query to find the 10 entries that lasted longest. I started with
=QUERY(known,"SELECT A, B, F-E label   F-E  'TopTen' " ,1)
which works fine but I can't find a way of ordering F-E and limiting the results. ORDER BY and LIMIT don't seem to work. I want to avoid creating a new calculated field in the data itself. Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: =QUERY(A:F,"SELECT A, B, F-E order by F-E desc limit 10 label F-E 'TopTen'" ,1) works for me

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(A:F, "select A,B,F-E order by F-E desc limit 10 label F-E'TopTen'", 1)
```

as per the documentation, clauses follow specific ordering:

[image]